# Flickering on product loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I learn React and explore various examples and tutorials. I tried to create an eshop according to the tutorial. But one thing is not clear to me. Flickers annoyingly while loading product or category. How could you get rid of it? What causes it?

Its this part of code:

```
export default function ProductScreen(props) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const productId = props.match.params.id;
  const [qty, setQty] = useState(1);
  const productDetails = useSelector((state) => state.productDetails);
  const { loading, error, product } = productDetails;
  const userSignin = useSelector((state) => state.userSignin);
  const { userInfo } = userSignin;

  const productReviewCreate = useSelector((state) => state.productReviewCreate);
  const {
    loading: loadingReviewCreate,
    error: errorReviewCreate,
    success: successReviewCreate,
  } = productReviewCreate;

  const [rating, setRating] = useState(0);
  const [comment, setComment] = useState('');
```

Here is example: https://amazona.webacademy.pro/
Here is full code: https://github.com/basir/amazona/blob/master/frontend/src/screens/ProductScreen.js

Thanks